# WAMP change Apache version

Tags: apache-http-server, php, wamp

I have WAMP installed with PHP 5.5.12 and Apache 2.4.9. I need to use PHP 5.1.0 so I installed it. Now I need to change the version of Apache as well but I do not know how.

What Apache version do I even need in order to use PHP 5.1.0? Where do I get it from and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

First, the place where you can get additional versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP to add to Wamp is this one: [Wamp Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202%20-%20Extensions/). Just go to this  sourceforge for wamp project, click on **Apache**, choose the *exe* you would like to add and download it. Execute it and it will add it to your wamp with a nice GUI installer. Then, when you clic on the Wamp icon in clock tray, use the menu that shows up and go to `Apache --> Apache version`, you will see that there will be more versions with the current one checked. If you click on a given version, it will reload with that one.

Second, if you have Wamp 2.5, these extensions are unlikely to work and you should install Wamp 2.4 instead.

Third, PHP 5.1.0 should work with Apache 2.0.49.

Fourth, if your Apache + PHP combination doesn't work, Wamp will remain with orange icon.

***UPDATE:*** I tested it in order to help you getting it working. First I installed WampServer 2.4 x86 (sometimes x64 has hiccups working with extensions, I just play it safe but you can test it!)

[image]

[image]

Then I downloaded Apache 2.0.50 and PHP 5.1.0 from the Extensions section.

[image]

I executed both exe files, Apache first, PHP later. Do not remove the PHP inclued as it has some Wamp functionalities configured to be executed via CLI.

After that, I started Wamp and changed Apache version so the checked one would be 2.0.50. THEN I changed PHP version to 5.1.0.

[image]

I installed the apache service using `apache -- service -- remove service`, `apache -- service -- test port 80` and `apache -- service -- install service` to remove previous service with the bundled apache and install the new one. Check that no httpd.exe process is running so you can successfully install the new service. It might get stucked in a point here. Kill it if necessary.

[image]

Exit wamp. Start it again. Check that the service is available in `apache -- service` to start, stop and restart. It means it's installed the right way.

The final changes to make it work:

- Check that Apache can manage IPv6. Edit the alias configured for Apache. All the .conf in `C:/wamp/alias` have some access directives with a line `Allow for ::1`. Comment it putting a # in front of it.
- Check that the modules loaded by PHP actually exist. It might throw a couple of alerts for missing php_sqli and php_pdo. In the end, it might be a running wamp with Apache 2.0.50 and PHP 5.1.0

[image]

Comment: I have done so but it doesn't work. It shows both versions of Apache (2.0.49 and 2.4.9) and PHP (5.1.0 and 5.5.12), however I cannot switch between them as I get the message: This Apache version doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual PHP Version. Switch canceled.

Comment: I get this php error:
[08-Sep-2015 10:36:11 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  require(c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.1.0/wampserver.conf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 80
[08-Sep-2015 10:36:11 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. switchPhpVersion() C:\wamp\scripts\switchPhpVersion.php:9
[08-Sep-2015 10:36:11 Europe/Paris] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.1.0/wampserver.conf' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\scripts\wampserver.lib.php on line 80

Comment: @user112111223 How did you install PHP 5.1.0? You must install the extension as well, not the whole PHP...

Comment: I installed it from the link that you provided in your answer (Wamp Sourceforge). I chose the WampServer2-PHP510.exe file and installed it

Comment: @user112111223 Answer updated. Hope it helps! Please make sure you uninstall previous wamp installations.